# How can I select the maximum value for each position from two stacked transitionLayers in R?

Tags: r, max

In order to conduct least cost analyses in R, I am trying to produce the cost surface from a DEM. I want to treat land areas in a different way from sea areas (sea costs being half of land travel costs on a plain). To do so, I have produced **two transition layers** which I calculated with two different `transitionFunction` (altDiff). (`geoCorrection` and the Tobler function I omitted here)

```
library(raster)
library(gdistance)

# functions ---------------------------------------------------------------
altDiff_land <- function(x) (x[2] - x[1])
altDiff_sea <- function(x) if((x[2]==0) & (x[1]==0)) { 0 } else { 99 }

# DEM ---------------------------------------------------------------------
dem <- raster(nrows=18, ncols=18)
dem <- setValues(dem, runif(ncell(dem),min = 0, max = 50))

# cost surface LAND -------------------------------------------------------
dem_land <- dem
land_trans <- transition(x = dem_land, transitionFunction = altDiff_land,
directions = 8, symm = FALSE)

# cost surface SEA --------------------------------------------------------
dem_sea <- dem
dem_sea[dem_sea[]>40] <- 1
dem_sea[dem_sea[]!=1] <- 0
sea_trans <- transition(x = dem_sea, transitionFunction = altDiff_sea,
directions = 8, symm = FALSE)
```

The next step would be to stack the two transition layers (land_trans, sea_trans) in order to select the maximum values from them producing a final transition layer that I can use for least cost analysis.

I tried

```
a <- stack(land_trans,sea_trans)
conductance <- max(a)
plot(raster(conductance))
text(raster(conductance))
```

(which is working in this example) but the problem is that with my original DEM (of 450 MB) I have never got a result (even with aggregating the DEM with factor 500!) which is either because the `max` function is incredibly slow or because it does not work well with transitionStacks/layers. Rasterizing the transition layers before the analysis is not an option since the `costDistance` function from gdistance needs a transition layer.

Is there an alternative for `max`?

It seems that the produced transitionlayers have **different amounts of values (x)** in their matrices. So, when I try

```
a_test <- land_trans
a_test@transitionMatrix@x[a_test@transitionMatrix@x<sea_trans@transitionMatrix@x]
    <- sea_trans@transitionMatrix@x
```

as an alternative for `max` all I get is

```
Warning message:
In a_test@transitionMatrix@x[a_test@transitionMatrix@x < 
test_sea@transitionMatrix@x] <- test_sea@transitionMatrix@x :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

But the DEMs are of the same size! Why do the transitionlayers differ? Can I force them to have identical sizes?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (see the help files in the distance package for examples).

Comment: Ok, I took out what seemed to be superfluous. Where do I find these help files?

Comment: It looks better now, but there still is `raster("lcp-base.tif")` which we cannot reproduce. You can create a similar object in memory `dem <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)` etc.  You have not seen the R help files? try `help("transition")`  `?stack`, `?transitions`, or `?terrain` for elevation data.

Comment: Now it should be reproducible. Thanks for your patience, Robert!